# Error: Could not find or load main class java_openweathermap.Weather

Tags: java, json, eclipse, parsing, chatbot

I am trying to complete an assignment with give me two tasks. I am getting stuck in the first part that says to make web requests to receive data. This is the code i am having trouble with compiling. I've been looking to see where i went wrong but don't seem to find the issue.

```
package java_openweathermap;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Weather {

    static final String URL_Weather_weather_London_uk =
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String result = "";

    try {
        URL url_weather = new URL(URL_Weather_weather_London_uk);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url_weather.openConnection();

        if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
                new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader, 8192);
            String line = null;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                result += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();

            String weatherResult = ParseResult(result);

            System.out.println(weatherResult);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()!!!");
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Weather.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Weather.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Weather.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
}

static private String ParseResult(String json) throws JSONException{

    String parsedResult = "";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

    parsedResult += "Number of object = " + jsonObject.length() + "\n\n";

    //"coord"
    JSONObject JSONObject_coord = jsonObject.getJSONObject("coord");
    Double result_lon = JSONObject_coord.getDouble("lon");
    Double result_lat = JSONObject_coord.getDouble("lat");

    //"sys"
    JSONObject JSONObject_sys = jsonObject.getJSONObject("sys");
    String result_country = JSONObject_sys.getString("country");
    int result_sunrise = JSONObject_sys.getInt("sunrise");
    int result_sunset = JSONObject_sys.getInt("sunset");

    //"weather"
    String result_weather;
    JSONArray JSONArray_weather = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
    if(JSONArray_weather.length() > 0){
        JSONObject JSONObject_weather = JSONArray_weather.getJSONObject(0);
        int result_id = JSONObject_weather.getInt("id");
        String result_main = JSONObject_weather.getString("main");
        String result_description = JSONObject_weather.getString("description");
        String result_icon = JSONObject_weather.getString("icon");

        result_weather = "weather\tid: " + result_id +"\tmain: " + result_main + "\tdescription: " + result_description + "\ticon: " + result_icon;
    }else{
        result_weather = "weather empty!";
    }

    //"base"
    String result_base = jsonObject.getString("base");

    //"main"
    JSONObject JSONObject_main = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
    Double result_temp = JSONObject_main.getDouble("temp");
    Double result_pressure = JSONObject_main.getDouble("pressure");
    Double result_humidity = JSONObject_main.getDouble("humidity");
    Double result_temp_min = JSONObject_main.getDouble("temp_min");
    Double result_temp_max = JSONObject_main.getDouble("temp_max");

    //"wind"
    JSONObject JSONObject_wind = jsonObject.getJSONObject("wind");
    Double result_speed = JSONObject_wind.getDouble("speed");
    //Double result_gust = JSONObject_wind.getDouble("gust");
    Double result_deg = JSONObject_wind.getDouble("deg");
    String result_wind = "wind\tspeed: " + result_speed + "\tdeg: " + result_deg;

    //"clouds"
    JSONObject JSONObject_clouds = jsonObject.getJSONObject("clouds");
    int result_all = JSONObject_clouds.getInt("all");

    //"dt"
    int result_dt = jsonObject.getInt("dt");

    //"id"
    int result_id = jsonObject.getInt("id");

    //"name"
    String result_name = jsonObject.getString("name");

    //"cod"
    int result_cod = jsonObject.getInt("cod");

    return
        "coord\tlon: " + result_lon + "\tlat: " + result_lat + "\n" +
        "sys\tcountry: " + result_country + "\tsunrise: " + result_sunrise + "\tsunset: " + result_sunset + "\n" +
        result_weather + "\n"+
        "base: " + result_base + "\n" +
        "main\ttemp: " + result_temp + "\thumidity: " + result_humidity + "\tpressure: " + result_pressure + "\ttemp_min: " + result_temp_min + "\ttemp_max: " + result_temp_min + "\n" +
        result_wind + "\n" +
        "clouds\tall: " + result_all + "\n" +
        "dt: " + result_dt + "\n" +
        "id: " + result_id + "\n" +
        "name: " + result_name + "\n" +
        "cod: " + result_cod + "\n" +
        "\n";
}
}
```

once i compile, i get the error in the title.

secondly, how can i connect the web request with a chat bot. 
thanks for your time!!! This might sound dumb, but do i just include the chat bot in the header? am i over thinking it? These concepts are fairly new to me so i'm not familiarized with this yet.

Comment: Is your code snippet a source file that is located in the `src` folder of an [Eclipse Java project](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-3.htm)?

Comment: What's doing the compilation? This doesn't sound like a Problem as Eclipse would show in its Peoblems View.

Comment: shall i add a screenshot of the src folder and the errors box?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error `Could not find or load main class java_openweathermap.Weather`

It seems class file is not created for your class Weather. It can be because of many reasons:

- Are you compiling your code using IDE like Eclipse? If yes, make sure your project is a [Java project](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-3.htm) and check if you have added ***gson.jar* in your build path** since you are using `import org.json.`...`;`. [Download *gson.jar* from here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1) and add the JAR manually to your build path.
- If you are compiling by terminal (on command line), *gson.jar* is required also in your base src directory to reference JSON objects. you can add it to run time\environment as well.
- Sometimes IDE gives this error even if everything in place. This you can fix it by cleaning and building the project again.Go to MENU->PROJECT->CLEAN and build again. Check if class file is created under bin\
  java_openweathermap\Weather.class

For chat bot,you can follow this [link](https://www.chatbots.org/ai_zone/viewthread/1615/)

Hope this helps. You can place your errors in details if you have any further assistance required.

Comment: I have done the clean part but still obtain the same error. I have the gson.jar path in the project. the one i have yet to do but will try is the second bullet point. Would the help change if i didn't mention the other error because the other error states "Archive for required library: 'src/java_openweathermap/Weather.java' in project 'APIs' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file"

Comment: Are you using IDE to compile? Please paste complete error trace here.

Comment: Archive for required library: 'src/java_openweathermap/Weather.java' in project 'APIs' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file                                                    The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Comment: Can you please provide complete steps of what are you doing? It doesn't  give any clue. It seems that you are trying to run a file which has build path errors.

Comment: all im trying to do is run the program. when i do, it says those two errors. Trying to send information to an api and have it send back information requested through a bot.

Comment: I verified that Weather.java does not have any error. You can check under Markers and see if any errors. You can add a screen shots of your project structure, libraries and error you receive.

Comment: I just tried to replicate this in another problem-Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/ab48917/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.6.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar' in project 'hibernate-one-to-one-example' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file hibernate-one-to-one-example
I just deleted the downloaded jar and run the clean install again. Finally I updated the Maven project. It solved the  issue. Let me know if you are using maven or any build tool to build the project and I will guide you.